# Write a java application to model a dog with attributes and behaviours

Tags: java, notepad++

I'm doing an assignment for college

"Write a Java application which models a dog who's attributes and behaviours are illustrated in
the UML diagram below (size: int, breed: String, name: String, Dog(), bark():void) Your submission should include a Dog class and a tester class. The tester class will create an instance of the Dog class and sets the size, breed and name of the dog
object, it should also call the bark method"

I nearly haver the code right but I can't get it to run it says: "could not find or load main class"

Could someone please have a look at the code and tell me if I have it right and how do I get it to run, I'm using Notepad++

```
class Dog {
    int size;
    String name;
    String breed;

    void bark() {
        if (size>60) {
            System.out,println("Woof! Woof!");
        }
        else if (size >14) {
            System.out.println("Ruff! Ruff!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Yap! Yap!");
        }
    }
}

class DogTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dog one = new Dog();
    one.size = 70;
    Dog two = new Dog();
    two.size = 8;
    Dog three = new Dog();
    three.size = 35;

    one.bark();
    two.bark();
    three.bark();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have researched before asking your question (moreover it was probably explained in your courses how to compile and run a program), but I'll tell you how to do.

Open a command line console and go yo the directory of your project. You don't seem to use packages so you will most likely be able to compile your sources by executing

```
javac *.java
```

To run the program, use

```
java DogTester
```

Answer (score 0):

first compile your all classes as :

```
javac *.java
```

run as :

```
java YourClass  //which contains main method
```

here you are missing dot

`System.out,println("Woof! Woof!");`

it should be
 `System.out.println("Woof! Woof!");`